Why do we only care for (and count) energy eigenstates and not superpositions in quantum statistical mechanics?
Consider one quantum particle in a 3D box in the microcanonical ensemble. It's energy eigenvalues are:
\begin{equation*}
   \varepsilon = \frac{h^2}{8mL^2}
                 (n_x^2+n_y^2+n_z^2)
\end{equation*}
The question is, when computing the microstates in this system, why do we only count energy eigenstates? In other words, why not counting possible superpositions too.
With only these two states i can make infinitely many different states:
\begin{equation*}
       \alpha |1,0,0\rangle
       + \beta |0,1,0\rangle
\end{equation*}
A related concept is, when calculating the partition function, why do we only sum over energy eigenstates. Or, more generally, why do we only need to sum over a complete basis.
This is an old doubt i've had since i first studied statistical mechanics.
Related questions i've found but haven't really made it clearer for me.
Why are accessible states taken as eigenstates in statistical physics? Is the resolution via decoherence?
Superposition of eigenstates in statistical mechanics
Why aren't superpositions of quantum states included in the partition function for a quantum particle
Does Decoherence explain why constituents of composite systems in textbook Statistical Mechanics are assumed to occupy energy eigenstates?

You need a set of mutually exclusive and exhaustive events/outcomes.

can you expand on the mutually exclusive part?

I'd suggest reading e.g. "Mutually Exclusive and Exhaustive Quantum States" by Park and Band, 1975.

I'll read into it. Thanks!!

Superposition is a property of the theory which describes an ensemble. It's not a property of the individual physical system. When you are evaluating an actual physical expression you can only sum over energetic states that the individual system can take on. More precisely, quantum mechanics is about quanta of energy and not particles. The only quanta that this system can exchange with its environment are the energy differences of allowed transitions between eigenstates. Technically that would also depend on the detailed coupling to the environment.

thanks for your answer. "When you are evaluating an actual physical expression you can only sum over energetic states that the individual system can take on." Why? I understand you should sum over any state the system can take on. Unless you are implying that a superposition isn't a real state.

@FlatterMann Sorry, but I think what you say has little relevance here. Mathematically, "being in a superposition" is (almost) always true. Even more, if you have a degenerate (energy) eigenvalue, then any corresponding eigenvector can be written as a superposition of eigenvectors with the same energy. Then there is also no preferred eigenbasis (of the Hamiltonian alone). The point of Stat. Mech is, very roughly, to find a good description of the (quantum) state, given some data, as e.g. expectation values of observables, see e.g. my comment in the first linked question.

@TobiasFünke A three dimensional vector is the superposition of three basis vectors. In a different basis it's a different superposition even though the vector itself hasn't changed. Superposition is a completely meaningless concept at the physical level. It shows up in quantum mechanics because the quantum mechanical ensemble is independent and unitary. From that we can construct linear vector/Hilbert spaces, but since ensembles are abstracts, so are these spaces. They are not real and neither are their elements. SM changes nothing about the distinction between physical/non-physical.

What Tobias said is true. On top of that, when you are filling up the states from lowest energy eigenstates upwards, filling up a full "shell" of states means that any superposed combination of those states will also have the same enumeration and be filled too. So, the superposition part will just not matter until the last few states. The last few states are boundary conditions and thus not in the thermodynamic limit.
